# Find the correct village name from a list of misspeled village names using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames df1 and df2. df1 consists of correct village names whereas df2 consists of wrong/misspelled village names. Now I want to find out the correct village names corresponding to those wrong/misspelled village names. As I am very new to Python, please guide me in this regard.

Comment: Show your actual data and the code you have already or you are unlikely to get any assistance.

Comment: you should indeed share your code. An alphabetical sorting could be an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well friend, you didn't provided your code so I'm assuming on my own
You can understood by my sample code

According to your problem, I suggest you to use `fuzzywuzzy`
You can install through cmd 
`pip install fuzzywuzzy`

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

# As I don't know your column name I'm assuming it on my own
df1 = {}
df2 = {}

df1['correct_name'] = ['jaipur','mumbai','ajmer','goa','sikkim']
df2['wrong_name'] = ['jepuor','mumbayi','amer','ga','goa','gooa','skim','jpur','moombi']

#You can customize and use accordingly
for items in df2['wrong_name']:
    found = process.extractOne(items,df1['correct_name'])
    print(items,' found similar to ',
          found[0],
          ' with percentage ',
          found[1])
```

My output is

```
jepuor  found similar to  jaipur  with percentage  67
mumbayi  found similar to  mumbai  with percentage  92
amer  found similar to  ajmer  with percentage  89
ga  found similar to  goa  with percentage  80
goa  found similar to  goa  with percentage  100
gooa  found similar to  goa  with percentage  86
skim  found similar to  sikkim  with percentage  80
jpur  found similar to  jaipur  with percentage  80
moombi  found similar to  mumbai  with percentage  67
```

You can read about this module at https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/

Comment: This solution works, but is extremly unperformant. Especially you should not call `process.extractOne` multiple times.

Comment: thank you @rish_hyun  now I can proceed atleast in a direction.

Comment: @maxbachmann I agree, I shall edit now